# Codename One - transparent foreground and fonts

Tags: codenameone, transparency

I have not yet found any option to provide transparency to the foreground color of a component, or to the font for that matter.

What I want to do is:

```
    Label halfTransparentLabel = new Label("Half Transparent text");
    Style s = halfTransparentLabel.getAllStyles();
    s.setBgColor(0);
    s.setBgTransparency(255);
    s.setFgColor(0xffffff);
    s.setFgTransparency(128); // this method does not exist
```

I know drawing translucent stuff is heavy on the performance, but I want to do it on particular pieces only. would greatly improve the visual appeal and design, having this option.

Can this be worked around?

Comment: There is no foreground transparency in Codename One but there is opacity which lets you set the level of opacity for all the elements within the component including foreground.

Comment: Thank you Shai, I was unaware of it, so I've just updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER

Thanks to the [Shai's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605483/codename-one-transparent-foreground-and-fonts/57611279#comment101692729_57605483), I update my answer. The workaround I suggested is not necessary. The same result of the posted screenshot can be obtained with https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/plaf/Style.html#setOpacity-int- or with the `opacity` property in the CSS, for example:

```
BigLabel {
    font-size: 6mm;
    font-family: "native:MainRegular";
    color: red;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

---

OLD ANSWER - Yes, it's possible to workaround this problem using the `.toImage()` method, as in this screenshot:

[image: Codename One Semi-transparent text]

I'm not sure if this workaround is the best, however it works.
The code of this example:

```
Form hi = new Form("Semitransparent Example", BoxLayout.y());
hi.getToolbar().setUIID("Transparent");
hi.setUIID("FormBackground");

Container cnt = FlowLayout.encloseIn(new Label("Half Transparent Text", "BigLabel"));
// .setSize() and .revalidate(), in this case, are necessary to use the .image() method
cnt.setSize(new Dimension(hi.getContentPane().getWidth(), CN.convertToPixels(8, false)));
cnt.revalidate();
hi.add(cnt.toImage().modifyAlpha((byte) 125));

hi.show();
```

and the CSS:

```
#Constants {
    includeNativeBool: true; 
}

Transparent {
    background-color: transparent;
}

FormBackground {
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
}

BigLabel {
    font-size: 6mm;
    font-family: "native:MainRegular";
    color: red;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers. with the above tips, the easiest solution in code is the following:

```
component.getAllStyles().setOpacity(128);
```

so what is the benefit to use CSS?

Having the designer to all the formating and styling, I already hate to do some parts in code and some in the designer. So why make it even more complex by introducing CSS? is CSS support supposed to replace the designer?